# MySQL inner join query with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I'm used to do MySQL querys only with one table. Now I need to connect two and have no idea :/

Table: **cat_member**

member | cat

11 | 3

14 | 4

12 | 3

Table: **members**

id | company

11 | Foo

14 | Bar

....

I want to select from cat_member where cat=3 for example and display the company names from the table members

This is how far I've come:

```
SELECT cat_medlem.member, 
members.company
FROM members
WHERE cat_medlem.cat = 3
INNER JOIN members
ON cat_member.member=members.id
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where condition should go after the join, also you probably looking to join `members` with `cat_member`

```
SELECT cat_member.member, 
members.company
FROM members
INNER JOIN cat_member
ON cat_member.member=members.id
WHERE cat_member.cat = 3
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks :) Makes a lot more sense. I will accept the answer in 8 minutes :)